# How can I disassembly win16 with GDB

Tags: gdb, disassembly

I am in need to debug bouncing ball virus (note that it is written in **win16** asm) to finish my essay. Attempting to use GDB but it said:

> not in executable format. File format unrecognized.

My problem is: Is it possible to use GDB to finish that?

If yes, what should I do? If no, what else debugger can I use besides the Win's debug.exe?

Comment: Open Watcom http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page used to have a nice 16-bit debugger.  I have not looked at it in some years, so am not sure it's still supported.

Comment: @Gene Thanks for the advice. I have downloaded the software and it works well. It is just a pity that it seems can't work correctly in WinXP so I hosted a virtual machine to have my work done. Again, thanks ^_^.