# 16-bit assembly instructions decoded improperly by GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb, qemu, bootloader, x86-16

I am trying to reverse my own code, its 16-bit Real mode assembly. I wrote the following function:

```
inc di
mov cx , [di]
add cl , 0x46
jo exit 
sub cl , 0x46
cmp cl , '0'
jl exit
sub cl , '5'
jns exit
jnp exit
```

after I compiled it and run in Qemu, the code is changed into the following code:

[image: code from gdb]

as you can see the first 3 line are different:

```
inc edi
mov ecx, DWORD PTR ds:0x7046c180
BYTE PTR es:[edi],dx
```

how this is possible? 
how the cpu knows to perform the commands:

```
mov cx , [di]
add cl , 0x46
jo exit
```

as far as I know the command :

```
mov ecx, DWORD PTR ds:0x7046c180
```

move the data from the pointer `0x7046c180` to `ecx`, but it's equal to `00000000`.

[image: dump]

Can someone explain to me why the compiler changed my instruction into this, and how it is working the same as my code without the `jo` instruction?

Comment: _GDB_ is probably assuming you are using 32-bit code, not 16-bit code. It has improperly decoded the instructions. After your code loads into _QEMU_ and you are in your remote debugging session with _GDB_ issue the command `set architecture i8086` . Debugging 16-bit code can become extremely problematic because _GDB_ has no real notion of how segment registers are used (it just knows their value). As well you can't easily step over interrupts. There is a link to a set of _GDB_ routines in this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32960272/3857942)  that may help a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disassemble 16-bit x86 boot sector code in GDB with "x/i $pc"? It gets treated as 32-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955887/how-to-disassemble-16-bit-x86-boot-sector-code-in-gdb-with-x-i-pc-it-gets-tr) . It may look like a different question, but is effectively the same thing. Instructions appear to be decoded in _GDB_ improperly. The answer also suggests a remedy.

Comment: GDB may have decoded them improperly because it didn't know they were 16-bit, but inside QEMU the instructions run as expected because QEMU knows it is running code in 16-bit real mode so executes the instructions properly. Effectively GDB is showing you gibberish, but QEMU is decoding and running the proper instructions.