# Lost while debugging INT 13h

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, bootloader, dos

I was debugging, through the Boot Loader from the FreeDos OS, till I got lost after the interrupt 13h instruction.
I use gdb with qemu.

```
gdb version: 7.11.1
qemu version: 2.5
FreeDos version: 1.2
```

I got to this point:

```
int 13h
```

and then I typed:

```
si (step instruction)
```

and then, when I examine the instruction pointer I got this:

```
add BYTE PTR [bx+si], al

add BYTE PTR [bx+si], al   

add BYTE PTR [bx+si], al

add BYTE PTR [bx+si], al
```

Obvious there shouldn't come these instructions. There should come:

```
jb     0xf2
```

The next thing, is that I can't get out of these weired instructions. They go one forever but when I type `c` (continue) then the program continues normally.
I tried several things but nothing worked out:
Set a breakpoint after the `int 13h` instruction but when I then pressed `c` the program didn't stopped there.
Also I tried to press `n` or `s`. Nothing worked.

My setup for qemu:

```
qemu-system-i386 -localtime freedos.img -boot d -S -s
```

And for gdb:

```
gdb -q
target remote localhost:1234
set architecture i8086
```

Why is this so? What am I missing?

Edit: It's the the check for extensions interrupt.

Comment: For real mode I'd recommend using BOCHS since its internal debugger actually understands real mode segment:offset addressing where as _GDB_ doesn't. I wrote an [answer that may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32960272/3857942). There is a link in the answer to a _GDB_ script that adds a new `stepo` instruction to handle a case like calling `int 13h`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. It helped.