# Memory Addressing in x86 Real Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, boot

I'm trying to follow the lab1 of MIT 6.828 to get some understanding about x86 bootstrapping.

The 1st instruction on boot up is:
`[f000:fff0]    0xffff0: ljmp   $0x3630,$0xf000e05b`

If I understand correctly, x86 compatible CPUs always start in real mode. I'm confused by the operands of this instruction. Is the first value `$0x3630` used as `cs` register in the long jump and the next part `$0xf000e05b` used as the offset?

If this is the case then the target address should be `0x36300 + 0xf000e05b` but the next instruction is `[f000:e05b]    0xfe05b: cmpw   $0xffc8,%cs:(%esi)` which is at `0xfe05b`. How is this address `0xfe05b` calculated? Does the CPU make use of the upper 16-bits of the EIP register at all in real mode?

I tried to set the architecture to be i8086 and inspect the instructions and they still seemed to be interpreted as 32-bit instructions.

```
(gdb) set architecture i8086
The target architecture is assumed to be i8086
(gdb) x/5i 0xffff0
   0xffff0:     ljmp   $0x3630,$0xf000e05b
   0xffff7:     das
   0xffff8:     xor    (%ebx),%dh
   0xffffa:     das
   0xffffb:     cmp    %edi,(%ecx)
(gdb)
```

Comment: How are you disassembling the instructions. `ljmp   $0x3630,$0xf000e05b` is a 32-bit instruction but the first boot instructions will likely be 16-bit code. TRy disassembling code at f000:fff0 as 16-bit and not 32-bit. When you decode as 16-bit code it will probably look like `ljmp  $0xf000:$e05b` which starts executing code at an earlier part of the BIOS ROM.

Comment: Come to think of it it looks like you might be in a  debugger?? Tell us how you are viewing this code (and which program) and we can probably tell you how to switch to 16-bit disassembly.

Comment: Yes I'm using gdb to debug qemu remotely through a port on localhost. I'm looking into how to switch to 16-bit disassembly. At the beginning of the debug session gdb already prints "The target architecture is assumed to be i8086".

Comment: Use an option that shows raw machine code as well, so we can be more sure of what the disassembler is doing.  Those instructions would require `66` operand-size  and/or `67` address-size prefixes in 16-bit mode, if they're really being disassembled correctly (which I doubt).  DAS is probably a byte that should have been another instruction.

Comment: There seems to be a gdb bug in recent versions that ignore the `set architecture i8086`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246894/547981) on the linked duplicate for a workaround. Also, consider using bochs with its built-in debugger which is better at handling real mode.