# Different instructions coming up on stepping through the code vs dumping memory contents in GDB

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, boot, xv6

I'm using `gdb` to inspect the boot process of [`xv6`](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/xv6.html). More specifically, I'm running `xv6` using `qemu` with `gdb` support in a terminal. And in another terminal, I'm running `gdb` remotely connected to the `qemu` stub.

Now, stepping through the boot process with the `si` command yields the following instructions

```
[f000:e05b]    0xfe05b: cmpw   $0xffc8,%cs:(%esi)
[f000:e062]    0xfe062: jne    0xd241d416
[f000:e066]    0xfe066: xor    %edx,%edx
[f000:e068]    0xfe068: mov    %edx,%ss
[f000:e06a]    0xfe06a: mov    $0x7000,%sp
[f000:e070]    0xfe070: mov    $0x2d4e,%dx
[f000:e076]    0xfe076: jmp    0x5575ff02
```

Whereas, dumping the instructions from memory directly using the `(gdb) x /20i 0xfe05b` command yields the following instructions

```
   0xfe05b: cmpw   $0xffc8,%cs:(%esi)
   0xfe060: jo     0xfe062
   0xfe062: jne    0xd241d416
   0xfe068: mov    %edx,%ss
   0xfe06a: mov    $0x7000,%sp
   0xfe06e: add    %al,(%eax)
   0xfe070: mov    $0x2d4e,%dx
   0xfe074: verw   %cx
   0xfe077: xchg   %ebx,(%esi)
   0xfe079: push   %bp
   0xfe07b: push   %di
   0xfe07d: push   %si
   0xfe07f: push   %bx
   0xfe081: sub    $0x70,%sp
   0xfe085: mov    %ax,%di
   0xfe088: mov    0x4(%bx,%si),%si
   0xfe08d: mov    %cs:0x2c(%bp),%bl
   0xfe093: icebp  
   0xfe094: ljmp   *(%esi)
```

As you can see the instructions are not the same at all; why is this the case? I suspect that `gdb` is failing to recognise where individual instructions end and begin, so it's interpreting them incorrectly. But then again, why so?

Comment: If `si` yields the top code, that means your cpu is in 32 bit mode but you disassembled in 16 bit mode. You do not see what the cpu is actually executing. Switch to 32 bit disassembly.

Comment: Debugging with QEMU can be problematic in 16-bit real mode. You may wish to start by using the GDB command `set architecture i8086` to decod

Comment: @MichaelPetch Setting the architecture to `i8086` didn't help. Also, `qemu` was already printing "`The target architecture is assumed to be i8086`", so I guess it got that right.

Comment: @Jester how do I do that? Also, this is the absolute start of the boot process, so shouldn't it be 16 bit real mode?

Comment: `f000:e05b` seems like BIOS code. You likely want to only debug your bootloader so place breakpoint at `0x7c00`.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246894/547981) for a possibly related bug and workaround.

Comment: @Jester Yeah you're right, this is BIOS code. But still, there should be some explanation for what's happening, right?

Comment: Jester and Michael already gave you an explanation: CPU in 32-bit mode but GDB decoding as 16-bit.  You need to set architecture to 32-bit if GDB is incorrectly assuming 16-bit.  Perhaps `i386`, or use `help set architecture`.