# QEMU gdb does not show instructions of firmware

Tags: debugging, x86, gdb, qemu, bios

I am trying to debug the bios.bin that comes with the QEMU emulator. I am starting QEMU as follows:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -bios bios.bin -s -S
```

I then start start debugging with:

```
gdb
target remote localhost:1234
```

GDB is at the Intel handoff state 0xfffffff0 where now the firmware/BIOS should be. However there is nothing at this location in memory. Even if step through a more instructions via `nexti` it decodes as all zeros.

What am I doing wrong or am I misunderstanding something? I basically want to get the first instruction the cpu calls and continue debugging from there.

Comment: Are you able to emulate without gdb? Need to triage where the problem is.

Comment: You mean when I normal run withou gdb ? Yes the bios works as it should be and shows up in qemu

Comment: Also if I put a watch on that address nothing happens when I continue. The bios runs as normal. If i put a break on that address its like an infinite breakpoint. Gets triggered again and again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QEMU isn't the problem here, but GDB is. I will start with a recommendations if you intend to use GDB to debug the BIOS:

- Do not use qemu-system-x86_64. Use qemu-system-i386 instead. This will avoid a packet too long problem and a pile of numbers being displayed. This may or may not happen to you depending on the version of GDB being used.

With that being said, GDB's real problem is that it has no knowledge of [real mode segment:offset addressing](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html). When you boot QEMU it starts in 16-bit real mode to start executing the legacy BIOS. GDB's lack of real mode debugging support is the real issue. You can read more about it in another [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32960272/3857942) I wrote. To summarize:

> Unfortunately by default gdb doesn't do segment:offset calculations
> and will use the value in EIP for breakpoints. You have to specify
> breakpoints as 32-bit addresses (EIP).
>
> When it comes to stepping through real mode code it can be cumbersome
> because gdb doesn't handle real mode segmentation. If you step into an
> interrupt handler you'll discover gdb will display the assembly code
> relative to EIP. Effectively gdb will be showing you disassembly of
> the wrong memory location since it didn't account for CS.

Over the years changes to GDB have made debugging real mode code more involved and negotiating connections to remote hosts has become more problematic. Based on my answer above and the other 2 answers under the same question you may be able to get this working satisfactorily on old and new versions of GDB by trying the following:

Make a file called `target.xml` with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE target SYSTEM "gdb-target.dtd">
<target>
    <architecture>i8086</architecture>
    <xi:include href="i386-32bit.xml"/>
</target>
```

Create a file called `i386-32bit.xml` with the [contents of this URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qemu/qemu/master/gdb-xml/i386-32bit.xml). Alternatively you can retrieve this file from the command line on Linux based OSes with:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qemu/qemu/master/gdb-xml/i386-32bit.xml
```

Create a script file called `gdb_init_real_mode.txt` with the following:

```
# Special mode for GDB that allows to debug/disassemble REAL MODE x86 code
#
# It has been designed to be used with QEMU or BOCHS gdb-stub
#
# 08/2011 Hugo Mercier - GPL v3 license
#
# Freely inspired from "A user-friendly gdb configuration file" widely available
# on the Internet

set confirm off
set verbose off
set prompt \033[31mreal-mode-gdb$ \033[0m

set output-radix 0d10
set input-radix 0d10

# These make gdb never pause in its output
set height 0
set width 0

# Intel syntax
set disassembly-flavor intel
# Real mode
#set architecture i8086

set $SHOW_CONTEXT = 1

set $REAL_MODE = 1

# By default A20 is present
set $ADDRESS_MASK = 0x1FFFFF

# nb of instructions to display
set $CODE_SIZE = 10

define enable-a20
  set $ADDRESS_MASK = 0x1FFFFF
end
define disable-a20
  set $ADDRESS_MASK = 0x0FFFFF
end

# convert segment:offset address to physical address
define r2p
  if $argc < 2
    printf "Arguments: segment offset\n"
  else
    set $ADDR = (((unsigned long)$arg0 & 0xFFFF) << 4) + (((unsigned long)$arg1 & 0xFFFF) & $ADDRESS_MASK)
    printf "0x%05X\n", $ADDR
  end
end
document r2p
Convert segment:offset address to physical address
Set the global variable $ADDR to the computed one
end

# get address of Interruption
define int_addr
  if $argc < 1
    printf "Argument: interruption_number\n"
  else
    set $offset = (unsigned short)*($arg0 * 4)
    set $segment = (unsigned short)*($arg0 * 4 + 2)
    r2p $segment $offset
    printf "%04X:%04X\n", $segment, $offset
  end
end
document int_addr
Get address of interruption
end

define compute_regs
  set $rax = ((unsigned long)$eax & 0xFFFF)
  set $rbx = ((unsigned long)$ebx & 0xFFFF)
  set $rcx = ((unsigned long)$ecx & 0xFFFF)
  set $rdx = ((unsigned long)$edx & 0xFFFF)
  set $rsi = ((unsigned long)$esi & 0xFFFF)
  set $rdi = ((unsigned long)$edi & 0xFFFF)
  set $rbp = ((unsigned long)$ebp & 0xFFFF)
  set $rsp = ((unsigned long)$esp & 0xFFFF)
  set $rcs = ((unsigned long)$cs & 0xFFFF)
  set $rds = ((unsigned long)$ds & 0xFFFF)
  set $res = ((unsigned long)$es & 0xFFFF)
  set $rss = ((unsigned long)$ss & 0xFFFF)
  set $rip = ((((unsigned long)$cs & 0xFFFF) << 4) + ((unsigned long)$eip & 0xFFFF)) & $ADDRESS_MASK
  set $r_ss_sp = ((((unsigned long)$ss & 0xFFFF) << 4) + ((unsigned long)$esp & 0xFFFF)) & $ADDRESS_MASK
  set $r_ss_bp = ((((unsigned long)$ss & 0xFFFF) << 4) + ((unsigned long)$ebp & 0xFFFF)) & $ADDRESS_MASK
end

define print_regs
  printf "AX: %04X BX: %04X ", $rax, $rbx
  printf "CX: %04X DX: %04X\n", $rcx, $rdx
  printf "SI: %04X DI: %04X ", $rsi, $rdi
  printf "SP: %04X BP: %04X\n", $rsp, $rbp
  printf "CS: %04X DS: %04X ", $rcs, $rds
  printf "ES: %04X SS: %04X\n", $res, $rss
  printf "\n"
  printf "IP: %04X EIP:%08X\n", ((unsigned short)$eip & 0xFFFF), $eip
  printf "CS:IP: %04X:%04X (0x%05X)\n", $rcs, ((unsigned short)$eip & 0xFFFF), $rip
  printf "SS:SP: %04X:%04X (0x%05X)\n", $rss, $rsp, $r_ss_sp
  printf "SS:BP: %04X:%04X (0x%05X)\n", $rss, $rbp, $r_ss_bp
end
document print_regs
Print CPU registers
end

define print_eflags
    printf "OF <%d>  DF <%d>  IF <%d>  TF <%d>",\
           (($eflags >> 0xB) & 1), (($eflags >> 0xA) & 1), \
           (($eflags >> 9) & 1), (($eflags >> 8) & 1)
    printf "  SF <%d>  ZF <%d>  AF <%d>  PF <%d>  CF <%d>\n",\
           (($eflags >> 7) & 1), (($eflags >> 6) & 1),\
           (($eflags >> 4) & 1), (($eflags >> 2) & 1), ($eflags & 1)
    printf "ID <%d>  VIP <%d> VIF <%d> AC <%d>",\
           (($eflags >> 0x15) & 1), (($eflags >> 0x14) & 1), \
           (($eflags >> 0x13) & 1), (($eflags >> 0x12) & 1)
    printf "  VM <%d>  RF <%d>  NT <%d>  IOPL <%d>\n",\
           (($eflags >> 0x11) & 1), (($eflags >> 0x10) & 1),\
           (($eflags >> 0xE) & 1), (($eflags >> 0xC) & 3)
end
document print_eflags
Print eflags register.
end

# dump content of bytes in memory
# arg0 : addr
# arg1 : nb of bytes
define _dump_memb
  if $argc < 2
    printf "Arguments: address number_of_bytes\n"
  else
    set $_nb = $arg1
    set $_i = 0
    set $_addr = $arg0
    while ($_i < $_nb)
      printf "%02X ", *((unsigned char*)$_addr + $_i)
      set $_i++
    end
  end
end

# dump content of memory in words
# arg0 : addr
# arg1 : nb of words
define _dump_memw
  if $argc < 2
    printf "Arguments: address number_of_words\n"
  else
    set $_nb = $arg1
    set $_i = 0
    set $_addr = $arg0
    while ($_i < $_nb)
      printf "%04X ", *((unsigned short*)$_addr + $_i)
      set $_i++
    end
  end
end

# display data at given address
define print_data
       if ($argc > 0)
          set $seg = $arg0
      set $off = $arg1
      set $raddr = ($arg0 << 16) + $arg1
      set $maddr = ($arg0 << 4) + $arg1

      set $w = 16
      set $i = (int)0
      while ($i < 4)
        printf "%08X: ", ($raddr + $i * $w)
        set $j = (int)0
        while ($j < $w)
              printf "%02X ", *(unsigned char*)($maddr + $i * $w + $j)
              set $j++
        end
        printf " "
        set $j = (int)0
        while ($j < $w)
              set $c = *(unsigned char*)($maddr + $i * $w + $j)
              if ($c > 32) && ($c < 128)
                 printf "%c", $c
              else
            printf "."
              end
              set $j++
        end
        printf "\n"
        set $i++
      end
      
      
       end
end

define context
  printf "---------------------------[ STACK ]---\n"
  _dump_memw $r_ss_sp 8
  printf "\n"
  set $_a = $r_ss_sp + 16
  _dump_memw $_a 8
  printf "\n"
  printf "---------------------------[ DS:SI ]---\n"
  print_data $ds $rsi
  printf "---------------------------[ ES:DI ]---\n"
  print_data $es $rdi

  printf "----------------------------[ CPU ]----\n"
  print_regs
  print_eflags
  printf "---------------------------[ CODE ]----\n"
  
  set $_code_size = $CODE_SIZE

  # disassemble
  # first call x/i with an address
  # subsequent calls to x/i will increment address
  if ($_code_size > 0)
    x /i $rip
    set $_code_size--
  end
  while ($_code_size > 0)
    x /i
    set $_code_size--
  end
end
document context
Print context window, i.e. regs, stack, ds:esi and disassemble cs:eip.
end

define hook-stop
  compute_regs
  if ($SHOW_CONTEXT > 0)
    context
  end
end
document hook-stop
!!! FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY - DO NOT CALL !!!
end

# add a breakpoint on an interrupt
define break_int
    set $offset = (unsigned short)*($arg0 * 4)
    set $segment = (unsigned short)*($arg0 * 4 + 2)

    break *$offset
end

define break_int_if_ah
  if ($argc < 2)
    printf "Arguments: INT_N AH\n"
  else
    set $addr = (unsigned short)*($arg0 * 4)
    set $segment = (unsigned short)*($arg0 * 4 + 2)
    break *$addr if ((unsigned long)$eax & 0xFF00) == ($arg1 << 8)
  end
end
document break_int_if_ah
Install a breakpoint on INT N only if AH is equal to the expected value
end

define break_int_if_ax
  if ($argc < 2)
    printf "Arguments: INT_N AX\n"
  else
    set $addr = (unsigned short)*($arg0 * 4)
    set $segment = (unsigned short)*($arg0 * 4 + 2)
    break *$addr if ((unsigned long)$eax & 0xFFFF) == $arg1
  end
end
document break_int_if_ax
Install a breakpoint on INT N only if AX is equal to the expected value
end

define stepo
  ## we know that an opcode starting by 0xE8 has a fixed length
  ## for the 0xFF opcodes, we can enumerate what is possible to have
  
  set $lip = $rip
  set $offset = 0
  
  # first, get rid of segment prefixes, if any
  set $_byte1 = *(unsigned char *)$rip
  # CALL DS:xx CS:xx, etc.
  if ($_byte1 == 0x3E || $_byte1 == 0x26 || $_byte1 == 0x2E || $_byte1 == 0x36 || $_byte1 == 0x3E || $_byte1 == 0x64 || $_byte1 == 0x65)
    set $lip = $rip + 1
    set $_byte1 = *(unsigned char*)$lip
    set $offset = 1
  end
  set $_byte2 = *(unsigned char *)($lip+1)
  set $_byte3 = *(unsigned char *)($lip+2)
  
  set $noffset = 0
  
  if ($_byte1 == 0xE8)
    # call near
    set $noffset = 3
  else
    if ($_byte1 == 0xFF)
      # A "ModR/M" byte follows
      set $_mod = ($_byte2 & 0xC0) >> 6
      set $_reg = ($_byte2 & 0x38) >> 3
      set $_rm  = ($_byte2 & 7)
      #printf "mod: %d reg: %d rm: %d\n", $_mod, $_reg, $_rm
      
      # only for CALL instructions
      if ($_reg == 2 || $_reg == 3)
    
    # default offset
    set $noffset = 2
    
    if ($_mod == 0)
      if ($_rm == 6)
        # a 16bit address follows
        set $noffset = 4
      end
    else
      if ($_mod == 1)
        # a 8bit displacement follows
        set $noffset = 3
      else
        if ($_mod == 2)
          # 16bit displacement
          set $noffset = 4
        end
      end
    end
    
      end
      # end of _reg == 2 or _reg == 3

    else
      # else byte1 != 0xff
      if ($_byte1 == 0x9A)
    # call far
    set $noffset = 5
      else
    if ($_byte1 == 0xCD)
      # INTERRUPT CASE
      set $noffset = 2
    end
      end
      
    end
    # end of byte1 == 0xff
  end
  # else byte1 != 0xe8
  
  # if we have found a call to bypass we set a temporary breakpoint on next instruction and continue 
  if ($noffset != 0)
    set $_nextaddress = $eip + $offset + $noffset
    printf "Setting BP to %04X\n", $_nextaddress
    tbreak *$_nextaddress
    continue
    # else we just single step
  else
    nexti
  end
end
document stepo
Step over calls
This function will set a temporary breakpoint on next instruction after the call so the call will be bypassed
You can safely use it instead nexti since it will single step code if it's not a call instruction (unless you want to go into the call function)
end

define step_until_iret
  set $SHOW_CONTEXT=0
  set $_found = 0
  while (!$_found)
    if (*(unsigned char*)$rip == 0xCF)
      set $_found = 1
    else
      stepo
    end
  end
  set $SHOW_CONTEXT=1
  context
end

define step_until_ret
  set $SHOW_CONTEXT=0
  set $_found = 0
  while (!$_found)
    set $_p = *(unsigned char*)$rip
    if ($_p == 0xC3 || $_p == 0xCB || $_p == 0xC2 || $_p == 0xCA)
      set $_found = 1
    else
      stepo
    end
  end
  set $SHOW_CONTEXT=1
  context
end

define step_until_int
  set $SHOW_CONTEXT = 0

  while (*(unsigned char*)$rip != 0xCD)
    stepo
  end
  set $SHOW_CONTEXT = 1
  context
end

# Find a pattern in memory
# The pattern is given by a string as arg0
# If another argument is present it gives the starting address (0 otherwise)
define find_in_mem
  if ($argc >= 2)
    set $_addr = $arg1
  else
    set $_addr = 0
  end
  set $_found = 0
  set $_tofind = $arg0
  while ($_addr < $ADDRESS_MASK) && (!$_found)
    if ($_addr % 0x100 == 0)
      printf "%08X\n", $_addr
    end
    set $_i = 0
    set $_found = 1
    while ($_tofind[$_i] != 0 && $_found == 1)
      set $_b = *((char*)$_addr + $_i)
      set $_t = (char)$_tofind[$_i]
      if ($_t != $_b)
    set $_found = 0
      end
      set $_i++
    end
    if ($_found == 1)
      printf "Code found at 0x%05X\n", $_addr
    end
    set $_addr++
  end
end
document find_in_mem
 Find a pattern in memory
 The pattern is given by a string as arg0
 If another argument is present it gives the starting address (0 otherwise)
end


define step_until_code
  set $_tofind = $arg0
  set $SHOW_CONTEXT = 0

  set $_found = 0
  while (!$_found)
    set $_i = 0
    set $_found = 1  

    while ($_tofind[$_i] != 0 && $_found == 1)
      set $_b = *((char*)$rip + $_i)
      set $_t = (char)$_tofind[$_i]
      if ($_t != $_b)
    set $_found = 0
      end
      set $_i++
    end

    if ($_found == 0)
      stepo
    end
  end

  set $SHOW_CONTEXT = 1
  context
end
```

This script provides features that allow a person to better debug real mode code. It will display the values of the segments and the registers and will attempt to resolve segment:offset addresses by properly computing a physical address to decode instructions from.

Once you have the 3 files above you can attempt to debug the BIOS this way:

```
qemu-system-i386 -bios bios.bin -s -S &
gdb -ix gdb_init_real_mode.txt \
        -ex 'set tdesc filename target.xml' \
        -ex 'target remote localhost:1234'
```

There are a number of additional commands added mentioned in my related answer linked to earlier. This script takes care of setting the architecture to i8086 and then hooks itself into gdb. It provides a number of new macros that can make stepping through 16 bit code easier:

> break_int : adds a breakpoint on a software interrupt vector (the way
> the good old MS DOS and BIOS expose their APIs)
>
> break_int_if_ah : adds a conditional breakpoint on a software
> interrupt. AH has to be equals to the given parameter. This is used to
> filter service calls of interrupts. For instance, you sometimes only
> wants to break when the function AH=0h of the interruption 10h is
> called (change screen mode).
>
> stepo : this is a kabalistic macro used to 'step-over' function and
> interrupt calls. How does it work ? The opcode of the current
> instruction is extracted and if it is a function or interrupt call,
> the "next" instruction address is computed, a temporary breakpoint is
> added on that address and the 'continue' function is called.
>
> step_until_ret : this is used to singlestep until we encounter a 'RET'
> instruction.
>
> step_until_iret : this is used to singlestep until we encounter an
> 'IRET' instruction.
>
> step_until_int : this is used to singlestep until we encounter an
> 'INT' instruction.

If you use the command above to launch QEMU you should see something like:

```
---------------------------[ STACK ]---
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
---------------------------[ DS:SI ]---
00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
---------------------------[ ES:DI ]---
00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
----------------------------[ CPU ]----
AX: 0000 BX: 0000 CX: 0000 DX: 0663
SI: 0000 DI: 0000 SP: 0000 BP: 0000
CS: F000 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 SS: 0000

IP: FFF0 EIP:0000FFF0
CS:IP: F000:FFF0 (0xFFFF0)
SS:SP: 0000:0000 (0x00000)
SS:BP: 0000:0000 (0x00000)
OF <0>  DF <0>  IF <0>  TF <0>  SF <0>  ZF <0>  AF <0>  PF <0>  CF <0>
ID <0>  VIP <0> VIF <0> AC <0>  VM <0>  RF <0>  NT <0>  IOPL <0>
---------------------------[ CODE ]----
   0xffff0:     jmp    0xf000:0xe05b
   0xffff5:     xor    BYTE PTR ds:0x322f,dh
   0xffff9:     xor    bp,WORD PTR [bx]
   0xffffb:     cmp    WORD PTR [bx+di],di
   0xffffd:     add    ah,bh
   0xfffff:     add    BYTE PTR [bx+si],al
   0x100001:    add    BYTE PTR [bx+si],al
   0x100003:    add    BYTE PTR [bx+si],al
   0x100005:    add    BYTE PTR [bx+si],al
   0x100007:    add    BYTE PTR [bx+si],al
0x0000fff0 in ?? ()
real-mode-gdb$
```

As you can see it prints out part of the data at the top of the stack, some memory regions common to real mode programs, the segment registers and the regular registers. The instructions have been properly decoded from the right place in memory. You should see the program starting to execute at 0xffff0. Some BIOSes might have a different first instruction but one of the first few instructions will be a FAR JMP to another place in the BIOS:

```
0xffff0:     jmp    0xf000:0xe05b
```

Comment: Wow! This is nice. Problem solved. Thanks. However it is alot If would never have come up with. Do you recommend any other debuggers that could work more easier ?

Comment: @0xff0 BOCHS has a very good debugger in it that properly handles real mode. You can also change the BIOS in BOCHS as well. By using the bios.bin file from QEMU you would at least be able to walk through at the start up sequence. THere is no guarantee the QEMU bios.bin would work as expected but it may be enough to walk through the code you are interested in.