# GDB showing wrong address to local variables

Tags: c, gcc, linker, gdb, osdev

The below code is an snippet from the 2nd stage loader program. It is running in `Real Mode` and gets called by the bootloader program. The problem is that GDB is showing wrong addresses to variables allocated in stack.

```
|------|------|------|
|Name  |GDB   |Actual|
|------|------|------|
|char a|0x7be7|0x7bfb|
|char b|0x7be6|0x7bfa|
|------|------|------|
```

#### Source:

```
__attribute__((noreturn)) 
void __main()
{
    char a = 'A';
    char b = 'B';
    while(1);
}
```

#### Disassembly:

```
00008000 <__main>:
    8000:   66 55                   push   ebp
    8002:   66 89 e5                mov    ebp,esp
    8005:   66 83 ec 10             sub    esp,0x10
    8009:   67 c6 45 ff 41          mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x1],0x41  <--- char a
    800e:   67 c6 45 fe 42          mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x2],0x42  <--- char b
    8013:   eb fe                   jmp    8013 <__main+0x13>
```

This file gets loaded at physical location `0x8000` by a custom bootloader.

#### QEMU and GDB

```
> qemu-system-i386 -fda build/boot.flp -s -S
> gdb loader.sym
  target remote localhost:1234
  set architecture i386
  b __main
  c
  s
  s
  p &a
    0x7be7 "" <-- Not EBP - 1
  p &b
    0x7be6 "" <-- Not EBP - 2

  info reg
  eax            0x0                 0
  ecx            0x0                 0
  edx            0x7de3              32227
  ebx            0x8000              32768
  esp            0x7bec              0x7bec
  ebp            0x7bfc              0x7bfc  <-- char a is at 0x7bfb and char b is at 0x7bfa
  esi            0x0                 0
  edi            0x0                 0
  eip            0x8013              0x8013 <__main+19>
  eflags         0x202               [ IF ]
  cs             0x0                 0
  ss             0x0                 0
  ds             0x0                 0
  es             0x0                 0
  fs             0x0                 0
  gs             0x0                 0
```

I do not really understand what is going on. Could it be the `-m16` option?

#### Compilation

```
gcc -std=c99 \
    -nostartfiles \
    -c \
    -g \
    -ffreestanding \
    -fno-pie \
    -fno-stack-protector \
    -m16 \
    -march=i386 \
    -Wpedantic \
    -Wextra \
    -Wall \
    -O0  bootloader/x86/phase2/loader.c -o $TEMPDIR/loader.o || exit

ld -m elf_i386 --nmagic --script=build/loader.ld $TEMPDIR/loader.o -o $TEMPDIR/loader.lo || exit

objcopy --only-keep-debug $TEMPDIR/loader.lo $SYMDIR/loader.sym||exit
objcopy -O binary $TEMPDIR/loader.lo $OBJDIR/LOADER.flt||exit
```

#### Linker Script (build/loader.ld)

```
ENTRY (__main)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x8000;                 /* Loader is loaded at 0x0000:0x8000 */
    .text :AT(0x0)
    {
        *.o (.text);
    }
    .data :
    {
        *.o (.data);
        *.o (.bss);
        *.o (.rodata);
    }
    /DISCARD/ : 
    {
        *(.eh_frame)
    }
}
```

#### Things I tried:

1. Using `-m32` instead of `-m16` and `.code16gcc` at the top of the C file.
2. Verified that GCC, GDB works perfectly when compilling a native application.
3. Used `--oformat binary` option in `ld` instead of `objcopy`

#### PS:

- GCC Version: 8.3.0
- GNU ld Version: 2.31.1
- Linux Debian 10

Comment: after `mov    ebp,esp` your ebp gets the value of esp. I am not sure if esp wasn't changed before calling your __main. Can you check it?

Comment: @rhaport the `MOV` statement worked. The `EBP` before the __main call was `0x00` and 'ESP` before the call was `0x7B80` (Thars the Stack TOP)

Comment: You removed the `.eh_frame` section in which the debugger is relying on to determine the position of stack data. Consider using the `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` option instead of discarding `.eh_frame` in the linker script

Comment: Don't use `-m32` as that would generate 32-bit code. `-m16` is correct if you want to generate 32-bit code that runs in 16-bit real mode. `.code16gcc` was what was used prior to the option `-m16` being added. If your GCC supports `-m16` use it instead of `.code16gcc`. GCC 4.9.x+ should support `-m16`.

Comment: @Micheal Petch: Am I doing something outside GCC spec, writing real mode part of 2nd Stage Bootloader is C, instead of Assembly.

Comment: Well the regular versions of GCC don't create code that will run on on 286 and earlier processors. GCC's generated code even with `-m16` will almost certainly need a 386+ processor. GCC wasn't really ever designed with 16-bit code in mind and `-m16` is a serious hack to shoehorn 32-bit like code to run in 16-bit real mode. GDB's debugger also has problems debugging 16-bit real mode code especially if you intend to debug assembly code. GDB doesn't support proper debugging when segments are non-zero. GCC will also generate addresses that may exceed the 16-bit segment limits.

Comment: Basically GDB isn't designed to debug 16-bit real mode code, and GCC wasn't ever designed to generate true 16-bit code. There is an [experimental fork of GCC](https://github.com/tkchia/gcc-ia16) that is intended to generate code that can be run on processors like the 8086/80186/80286 but it has bugs that may make cause problems.

Comment: @MichaelPetch using `dwarf-2` debug option, it worked for the example provided above. But part of the code is written in assembly and `NASM` do not generate `dwarf-2` output, so mixing C and assembly is still causing same problems. I am guessing, I will use Assembly language for the 16bit parts.

Comment: I would recommend trying to use the other option I mentioned above If the NASM instruction or the actual assembly instructions Rather than change the DWARF debugging type use `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` instead. Your problem with looking at NASM code (or assembly code for that matter) may be partially related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62522147/3857942 . I mentioned above that GDB wasn't designed to debug code running in real mode.

Comment: You may have to use `set architecture i8086` when running GDB and you may need to create an XML file like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62522147/3857942 . But unless I saw what you are observing or you asked another question I am just guessing. Your have GDB decoding as i386 but it really is i8086. The instructions appearing in the debugger aren't necessarily the ones being executed.